# Remove country code code from phone number

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving the contact list from device, now I want to remove country codes from numbers maybe one number will be have the country code with +1 or 01

How can I do it , I want to remove country codes from all numbers any country

Comment: Hey, can you show us how you get the data. Just want to see how is the number coming up when you fetch it from the contact list. We can then figure something out, like a more efficient solution for you

Comment: You have to know the format used. Is there always a leading `+` if there is a country code? Is the country code separated from the rest by a space or not?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do. There are plenty of resources online that has a list of country codes. I'll download them and compare them with each number in the contact list. And finally run whatever removal operation I have.

Edit:  Before running the above algorithm, I would first clean the data.

- Remove all whitespaces.
- Replace the leading 0 with + or vice versa depending on the available dataset

Comment: I have a list with country codes in my api and I can get but there is two issues, some users add the country code with +...... and some other users with 0..... also some devices use space after the country code and some device is not using space after device

Answer (score 0):

you can store them in a vector and when you retrieve the information you can skip the first elements which belongs to the country code. usually telephone numbers have 9 numbers besides country code. you can fix the output array indexes.

Comment: Phone numbers can have more or less than 9 numbers besides the country code, depending on the country.

Answer (score 0):

**only way to remove the country code from the phone number is after making sure to which country the phone number belongs to.**

if you are sure about +1 or 01 or any first two digit is the country code,

```
number.substring(2);
```

will give you the number.

Comment: That would not work for a country code of, say, `+49` (Germany).

Answer (score 0):

if this is still relevant.
since all numbers are 10 characters you can do
`number.substring(number.length - 10)`
this would take the last 10 digits regardless of the country code with plus or not

Answer (score 0):

aah hey, this question was asked earlier but anyways will answer it ..

**THE FOLLOWING CODE IS WRITTEN IN JAVA**

there are **2 ways** to solve this !

**1st**

```
    String abc="+91 9000000009";
    abc=abc.replaceAll(" ","");
    int count=0;String Num="";
    for(int i=abc.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(count<10)//change number 10 according to the preferred number of digits of Phone Number Excluding country code
        {
          Num=abc.charAt(i)+Num;
          count++;
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number Without Country Code : "+Num);
```

**2nd**

```
    String abc="+91 9000000009";
    abc=abc.replaceAll(" ","");
    String Num1=abc.substring(abc.length()-10);//change number 10 according to the preferred number of digits of Phone Number Excluding country code
    System.out.println("Number Without Country Code : "+Num1);
```

***Both The Ways Work Fine***

but in the **second way** if then is **less than '10'** then it would cause a **error** !